# how to substract values that come from different tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
 
Table 1
+--------+--------+
|  name  | amount |
+--------+--------+
| Thomas |     35 |
| Robert |     20 |
| Peter  |     15 |
| Josh   |     100|
+--------+--------+


Table 2
+--------+--------+
|  name  | amount |
+--------+--------+
| Thomas |      5 |
| Robert |      5 |
| Peter  |     10 |
| Josh   |     15 |
+--------+--------+
```

And I want to subtract one row from one column from another row from another column in a different table. The number of rows on each table is the same and I would want to subtract the 1st row (from Table 1) from the 1st row (from Table 2) and so on.

So I would end up with

```
 
Table 3
+--------+--------+
|  name  | amount |
+--------+--------+
| Thomas |     30 |
| Robert |     15 |
| Peter  |      5 |
| Josh   |     85 |
+--------+--------+
```

I've trying for hours how to do the deduction to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a 1-1 relationship, just `join`:

```
select name, t1.amount - t2.amount as amount
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 using(name)
```

For this to properly work, `name`s should be unique in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` the tables. Negate table2 amounts. `GROUP BY` the result:

```
select name, sum(amount)
from
(
  select name, amount from table1
  union all
  select name, - amount from table2
) dt
group by name
```

Will also handle names only found in one of the tables, or several times in a table.